# Como copiar tabla de un servidor a otro, sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Debo hacer una copia de una tabla de una BD de un servidor 1 a otra BD de un servidor 2. He leido sobre copias de una BD a otra desde el mismo servidor pero no de un servidor a otro. Habrá una forma de realizarlo en un SP o mediante una query?.
Leí tambien que se podia hacer mediante powershell pero no he encontrado mas información.
Alguna idea?

Mil gracias.

Comment: Tienes que mejorar un poco el escenario, porque es muy difuso. Existen varias posibilidades. Si los servidores son accesibles entre ellos por IP, puedes vincular un servidor al otro, y realizar una query. No tienen ni porque tener el mismo proveedor. Un ejemplo https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/08/19/vincular-un-servidor-mysql-a-sql-server/

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es un Linked Server y luego creas la tabla 2 haciendo un select hacia la tabla 1

Answer (score 0):

Se puede realizar de varias formas:
El que me resultó práctico fue la herramienta **Tablediff de SQL Server**, desde línea de comandos que compara tablas y genera el script para ejecutarlo en el servidor destino.
Luego puedes automatizar el script para ejecutarlo cada vez y de acuerdo al requerimiento mediante el Agente de SQlServer o mediante las tareas de Windows.

**Para ello se requiere:**

- Conectividad a nivel de base de datos entre los servidores origen y
  destino.
- Usuario_sql (datareader) en servidor origen.
- Usuario_sql (escritura) en el servidor destino.

**Otras Alternativas:**

1. Implementación de un trigger en la tabla desde el servidor origen
   para reflejar las operaciones DML en el servidor
   destino.(Configuración en el Servidor Origen).
2. Utilizando la herramienta de desarrollo SQL Server Data Tools(Visual Studio)
   mediante DACPAC (Configuración en Servidor Destino).
3. Utilizando el SSMS.